# Problema con Instanceof

Tags: javascript, json, class

Tengo la siguiente clase y el codigo

```js
class Perro {
    constructor(name, edad){
        this.edad = edad
        this.name = name
    }

    
}

const p = new Perro('chucho', 4)
console.log(p instanceof Perro)         // true
const str = JSON.stringify(p)
const par = JSON.parse(str)
console.log(par instanceof Perro)       // false
```

La constante p me dice que es instancia de Perro pero cuando hago serializacion y parseo no me lo reconoce como instancia de Perro. ¿Cual es el problema. ¿Puedo saber que es una instancia de la clase Perro?

Comment: Al usar [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) se pierden todas las características que establecen que el objeto `p` es una instancia de tu Clase. Por lo tanto cuando usas [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse), no queda rastro de dichas características. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) `JSON.parse()` devuelve

> El objeto, array, string, number, boolean o valor nulo, correspondiente al JSON text.

Cuando tú haces

```
console.log(par instanceof Perro);
```

es lógico que te devuelva falso. La variable `par` NO es instancia de `Perro`. En todo caso es una instancia de `object`.

**Edit**:

Si lo que en realidad quieres es obtener una instancia de `Perro`, cuando haces el `JSON.parse`, entonces, de acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript) y a la documentación de [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) puedes utilizar una de estas dos opciones:

```
let perroInstance = Object.assign(new Perro(), par);
```

Donde `par` es el objecto al que le hiciste el `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: ¿Y como puedo probar que tiene las mismas caracteristicas de la clase Perro? ¿Una a una las propiedades?

Comment: Esa es una pregunta diferente. Intentaré editar mi respuesta para responderla

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás transformando limones en limonada y esperas que la limonada salga de un árbol. Analizaremos algunos conceptos clave para que te quede más claro que es lo que sucede.

**¿Que es una instancia?**

En palabras simples una instancia es un objeto nuevo e independiente que contiene (hereda) los atributos y funcionalidades definidas en la clase original desde la cual se crea la instancia.

Nota: una instancia también puede ser llamada ejemplar de clase o objeto.

**¿Que hace `instanceof`?**

Confirmar el tipo de un objeto en tiempo de ejecución, en otras palabras revisar si la instancia fue creada de una clase en particular.

Llegado a este punto sabemos lo que hace `instanceof` y que es una instancia, pero...

¿Por qué `p` si es una instancia de `Perro` y no `str` y `par` a pesar de que son creados mediante `p` y `p` si nace desde `Perro`?

Bueno, esto sucede porque `JSON` y sus respectivas funciones transforman los datos y no retornan una instancia de `Perro`, más bien trabajan creando su propio valor de retorno independiente al tipo de entrada.

**¿Que hace `JSON.stringify()`?**

El método `JSON.stringify()` convierte un objeto o valor de JavaScript en una cadena de texto JSON.

Si nos damos cuenta la función usará nuestro valor de entrada para crear el suyo, eso quiere decir que perdimos la instancia original y obtendremos un valor totalmente diferente retornado por la función.

**¿Que hace `JSON.parse()`?**

El método `JSON.parse()` analiza una cadena de texto como JSON, transformando opcionalmente el valor producido por el análisis.

Más de lo mismo, nos entregará un valor diferente al de la entrada.

En resumen, `p` si es una instancia de `Perro` ya que esta surge de la clase y no ha sufrido manipulación alguna.

`str` y `par` no son instancias de `Perro` ya que al usar los métodos de `JSON` retornan un valor estandarizado que no es creado desde la clase `Perro`.

Comment: Ok. Gracias. Mi idea era enviar objetos de clase a traves de websocket de un nodo a otro y cuando recibo el objeto, lo que necesito es obtener el objeto enviado y comprobar que es una instancia de la clase inicial. Parece que puedo hallar la solucion con Object.assign

Comment: Eso da para otra pregunta, pero debes entender que un objeto no es lo mismo que una estructura de datos, la estructura de datos es un conjunto de datos ordenados de una forma particular, mientras que un objeto se diferencia de una estructura de datos por poseer métodos y funcionalidades que hacen algo.
Para la comunicación se utilizan estructuras de datos y no objetos, ya que si tu websocket está en PHP tu clase (objeto) de javascript no funcionará, por lo cual debes transformar previamente tu objeto a una estructura de datos para que el receptor pueda recopilar bien la información.

Comment: César, excelente explicación teórica!

Comment: Ok. ya lo entiendo. Es por eso que cuando recibo el dato (JSON.parse()), no obtengo el objeto sino una estructura de datos derivada de JSON.stringify(). Por eso me da error cuando intento llamar a un metodo de la estructura de datos recibida, ya que yo pensaba que era mismo objeto enviado. La idea era que necesitaba poder probar que el dato recibido tenia estructura de objeto con instanceof pero para ello tendre que usar Object.assign